# Error Connecting to Google Cloud SQL from Cloud9 IDE

Tags: python, google-cloud-sql, cloud9-ide

I have my Cloud9 IP address whitelisted in my Cloud SQL console.

`hostname` is my Cloud SQL IPv6 address.

Using Python MySQLdb to connect:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(hostname,username,password,database)
```

Getting error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hostname' (101)")
```

'hostname' is my IPv6 in the error message.  Does anyone have suggestions on how I could troubleshoot whether my Cloud9 IP address is the correct address to whitelist?  Could it also be an issue with using IPv6?  I also don't know what the (101) error is, as I've seen other questions with different error codes for bad user/password.

Comment: MySQL error 101 is 'network unreachable'. The Cloud9 IP address to whitelist should be the external IPv4 address listed in the console. Perhaps try testing with an IPv4 address on your CloudSQL instance to rule out an IPv6 issue?

Comment: I added an IPv4 address to my CloudSQL instance and it works fine.  So my whitelisted IP is correct.Seems to be a problem with using IPv6 and MySQLdb.

I saw in MySQL Connector for Python their is a 'force_ipv6' argument.  But nothing similar in MySQLdb.

I'll use the IPv4 for now ... it costs about $8/month.  I'll keep working on the free IPv6 and post if I find a solution.